# ¿Como obtener el usuario logueado desde una API en laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, api, autenticación

Hay algo que no termino de entender para poder empezar a diseñar mi API en laravel. Deseo que solo usuarios que se encuentren logueados en la aplicación sean capaces de consumir los recursos de la API.

Tengo entendido que debo enviar un token que identifique al usuario en cada petición que haga desde el cliente pero ¿de donde saco este token? Tenia pensado las siguiente forma:

1. Generar una cadena de caracteres aleatoria que será mi token cuando el usuario se loguee.
2. Enviarla al cliente en forma de cookie.
3. Almacenar el token también en la base de datos y relacionarlo de alguna forma con el usuario.
4. Cada vez que haga una petición enviar el token almacenado en la cookie desde el cliente y mapear al usuario por el mismo.

Pero hacerlo de esta manera me genera algunas dudas:

1. Se supone que el usuario podrá acceder a su cuenta desde distintos computadores, debo crear una tabla especifica en la base de datos para almacenar todos los tokens que pueda generar un usuario desde distintos clientes ?

Se que parece que me estoy respondiendo yo mismo la pregunta jaja pero la verdad deseo saber la forma más correcta de hacerlo.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se suele hacer para obtener un token especifico para cada usuario es mediante la encriptacion de sus propios datos para generarlo como por ejemplo estos:

```
 $userInfo = array(
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'pass' => $user->pass,
            'urlPhoto' => $user->urlPhoto,
            'description' => $user->description,
            'birthday' => $user->birthday,
            'city' => $user->city,
            'id_rol' => $user->id_rol,
            'id' => $user->id
        );
```

de esta forma el cliente le envía los datos a la API que los encripta y devuelve un token, ese token lo puedes enviar a la api como identificador de autorizacion en cada peticion y en el caso de ser incorrecto o faltar el token en un endpoint devolver un codigo de error.

Despues la API solo tendria que desencriptar y rescatar esos datos dentro del token.